# Required Field Validations not working on button click Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a button and on its click I perform an Ajax call to controller but required field validations are not working with that call.

Following is my model code :

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
public string Customer { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
public string Phone { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
public string Address { get; set; }
```

and following is my view code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Orders.Customer, new { @placeholder = "Enter Your Full Name" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Orders.Customer)
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Orders.Phone, new { @placeholder = "Enter Your Cell Number" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Orders.Phone)
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Orders.Address, new { @rows = 3, @cols = 2, @style = "width:300px;", @placeholder = "Enter Your  Complete Delivery Address" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Orders.Address)
<input id="btnsubmit" type="button"  value="Submit" />
```

and following is my button's click event:

```
$('#btnsubmit').click(function () {

var data = $('form').serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'products': ids }, true);
var url = '@Url.Action("GetIds", "Store")';
$.post(url, data, function (r) {
    alert("Order Submitted Successfully");
});

});
```

What should I do to get Validations working ?

Comment: Change the button to `type="submit"`, then handle the `$('form').submit()` function instead of the buttons `.click()` event. Then you can use `$(this).valid()` to check if the form is valid and not proceed with the ajax call (and validation messages will be displayed

Comment: AND use preventDefault to stop submission: `$('#formID').on("submit",function (e) { e.preventDefault(); ... `

Comment: OR add `return false;` as the last line of the script

Comment: By changing button type to submit it is not going to the json function instead it is going to ActionResult

Comment: @StephenMuecke it works fine after adding preventDefault(); How can i redirect to another page after successful operation ?

Comment: `$.post(url, data, function (r) {
    alert("Order Submitted Successfully"); location.replace("thankyou.html");
});`

Comment: WHat do your mean redirect. If you want to redirect DONT use ajax (its just pointless) Do a normal form submit and redirect in the POST method

Comment: @mplungjan location.replace add the new page url with existing..for example my current url is "Store/Product" by adding location.replace("Store/Index"); url becomes "Store/Product/Store/Index"

Comment: That is hard to believe. But try location.replace("/Store/Index") - also I agree with NOT using Ajax if you plan to redirect anyway

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you parse the form so it can get validated.

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#myForm");

$("#myForm").submit(function () {
    var $form = $(this);
    var isValid = $form.validate().valid();

    if (isValid === true) {
        var data = $('#myForm').serialize() + '&' + $.param({ 'products': ids }, true);
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetIds", "Store")';

        $.post(url, data, function (r) {
            alert("Order Submitted Successfully");
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#myForm");` is pointless (the form has already been parsed) and it should be just `var isValid = $form.valid();` and you need `return false;` at the end to prevent the default submit

Answer (score 0):

Client-side validation is off by default. Make sure you enable it through the web.config:

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled should also be on.